# FILESTREAM - Read and write a large file in FILESTREAM column

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlfilestream

Should I use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream` to read and write a `FILESTREAM` column?

For example:

```cs
var sqlCommand = sqlConnection3.CreateCommand();
sqlCommand.CommandText = "Select FileData.PathName() As Path, GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() As TransactionContext From PictureTable Where PkId = (Select Max(PkId) From PictureTable)"; 

var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
var filePath = (string)reader["Path"];
var transactionContext = (byte[])reader["TransactionContext"];
var sqlFileStream = new SqlFileStream(filePath, transactionContext, FileAccess.Read);
var data = new byte[sqlFileStream.Length];
sqlFileStream.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt16(sqlFileStream.Length));
```

In above code I can use the query shown here and directly access the `FileData`:

```sql
Select FileData From PictureTable Where PkId = (Select Max(PkId) From PictureTable)
```

What happens if don't use `SqlFileStream` and use `varbinary(max)` to read and write?

When SQL Server and Application installed in separate server, I have some problem in setup Windows Authentication to access SqlFileStream file path. How I can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft's doc, SqlFileStream is the appropriate solution (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/create-client-applications-for-filestream-data)). The SqlFileStream handles other things like file handles as data stored in a file stream is different from data stored in a row-based data file (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream?view=netframework-4.7.1)).

Hope this helps!